# Windows Phone: Dynamically Add Columns in Databound Items Control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to layout a grid so that it can have a dynamic number of columns and each data-bound control is automatically added to the correct column (based on its index within a data context).

Think about bowling frames and while there are usually always 10, I don't want to define 10 columns in XAML and add each frame individually. I'm trying to do it programatically.

Here's my XAML:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="BowlingPlayers" ItemsSource="{Binding Game.Players}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,20">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Column="1">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Frames}" >
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <Grid Loaded="BowlingGrid_OnLoaded">

                                </Grid>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border Height="64" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Loaded="BowlingFrame_OnLoaded">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Ball1}"/>
                                        <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1,0,0,1">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Ball2}"/>
                                        </Border>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Score}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Then in code-behind:

```
private void BowlingGrid_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

    var grid = (Grid)sender;

    if (grid.ColumnDefinitions.Any()) return;

    var player = grid.DataContext as BowlingPlayer;

    if (player != null) {                
        // Add columns for each frame
        foreach (var frame in player.Frames) {
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() {Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)});
        }
    }
}

private void BowlingFrame_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var border = (Border) sender;
    var frame = border.DataContext as BowlingFrame;
    var presenter = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(border);
    var grid = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(presenter) as Grid;

    if (grid != null) {
        var player = grid.DataContext as BowlingPlayer;

        if (player != null) {
            var frameIndex = player.Frames.IndexOf(frame);
            Grid.SetColumn(border, frameIndex + 1);                                      
        }
    }
}
```

It is "sort of" working, it appears that all the frames are being put into the first column, not their respective column indices.

Is there another way to lay this out without hard-coding widths in the XAML? It works if I use a horizontal StackPanel and give each frame (border) an explicit width and height, but I'd like it to scale to the available width.

Basically, a CSS3 flexbox equivalent layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the equivalent demo of the WPF `UniformGrid` here:

http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2009/01/uniform-grid/

After switching to that, it does work as intended! Don't need to use any custom code now.